# Conditional Probability Problem With Cards

Tags: probability

[image]

X = # of Aces

Y= # of Kings

$h(X$ | $y=2) =  \frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$

Need help with what to do next.

**Edit 1:** This is the function I came up with: $ h(X$ | $2) = \frac{ \displaystyle \binom{4}{x} \binom{44}{3-x}} {\displaystyle \binom{48}{3}} \enspace , 0 \le x \le 3$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You are selecting the other three cards from a deck of 48 (why?).

Comment: I posted what I tried above. Can you show me the rest of the steps?

Comment: I don't understand the logic of what you did.  In my suggestion the denominator should be $48 \choose 3$

Comment: I have been stuck on this problem for a while, if possible I would gain the most help if you explained it to me, and your reasoning at each step.

Comment: Basically you can assume the hand has two kings, so now you just have to draw three more cards.  You want the chance there are two aces among those three cards, but you are prohibited from drawing more kings.  That is where the $48 \choose 3$ comes from.

Comment: Why do you discard the remaining two kings from the deck? I would think there are still 50 cards to choose from. The number of remaining cards cannot be 50 because of the first condition? If you were able to select 50, than x=2 would not always hold?

Comment: Because you are given that $Y=2$, so the hand hand has exactly two kings.

Comment: If you allow the possiblity for more kings, than you cannot initially state Y=2, for that condition could become untrue, is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.  That is why I can discard the other kings.